# Host with multiple interface to forward packets to next hop

Tags: sdn, mininet

I am trying to have host with multiple interface at Mininet and ping from h1-h2 (topology can be seen from the attached figure). If I have flow rules at S1 to send packets over 3rd output port, directly to the S2 switch it works fine. But if i try to change the packet to follow 2nd output port of S1 which is connected to h3, the packet cannot go through S2.

I can ping from h1 to h3, or h1 to h4. Similarly, from h2-h3 and h2-h4. But not h1-h2 if i want to use h3 and h4 at the route. I assign routes for each hosts as:

```
h3.cmd("sudo ip route add 192.168.10.1 dev h3-eth1")
```

Also changed configuration of hosts as:

```
 h3.cmd("sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")
 h3.cmd("echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp")
```

I configured IP address of each interface and checked them after starting Mininet.
My simple topology:

What is the problem here I am facing? Does anybody have an idea?